# How to validate disabled Kendo Datepicker with jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-validate, kendo-datepicker

I'm validating my from with jQuery Validate,and I've disabled the user input to Kendo Date. But the validation for datepicker is not working when I applied `disabled="disabled"` to the Kendo datepicker.

Comment: use unbind to remove the event for that element

Comment: Hi..! Can you give the Example...Because i'm new to Jquery.

Comment: post some code to clarifiy the question

Comment: Please read ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

> the validation for datepicker is not working when I applied `disabled="disabled"`

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin will **never** be able to validate `disabled` fields among other things.

[See line 553](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L553):

```
.not( ":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled], [readonly]" )
.not( this.settings.ignore )
```

This behavior is hard-coded into the plugin and there is no option to disable it.

*([It cannot be disabled using the `ignore` option](http://jsfiddle.net/amy4sven/).)*